# Custom allocation mechanism

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am implementing own memory mechanism. Here is my code:

```
static tls::main_pool main_pool;
static tls::local_pool local_pool(main_pool);

void * operator new(size_t n) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    return local_pool.new_mem(n);
}

void operator delete(void * p) throw()
{
    local_pool.free_mem(p);
}
```

The problem is that there are some `operator delete` calls appears after my allocator has been destroyed and `operator new` calls while my allocator is initializing. How to handle that?

UPDATE: 
To be clear, I dont use operator new and delete in allocator, so problem in some system or library calls.

Comment: Don't use `operator new` to initialize your allocator.

Comment: @KerrekSB I dont use it. I allocate memory with malloc and calling operator new to this memory

Comment: Then change it to `return get_local_pool().new_mem(n)`, and make a function that guarnatees that the thing is initialized.

Comment: The wonders of C++ static initialization order :-)